# Can Linux flock(fd, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB) fail spuriously?

Tags: linux, nonblocking, file-locking, flock

Consider a situation where two processes make concurrent attempts at placing an exclusive lock on some file using `flock(fd, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)`.

As indicated, the attempts are *non-blocking*, so one of the two processes is supposed to fail with `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Here is my question: Does the (Linux) implementation of `flock()` guarantee that exactly one of the two processes will succeed in every such case? Or, is it possible that both end up failing with `EWOULDBLOCK` even when nobody else are interfering?

**In short, can `flock(fd, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)` ever fail spuriously with `EWOULDBLOCK`?**

I am mainly interested in the version of `flock()` offered by Linux, but information about `flock()` on other systems, such as OS X, is most welcome.

Also, I assume that the answer is the same regardless of whether the locks are exclusive (`LOCK_EX`) or shared (`LOCK_SH`). If not, let me know.

Comment: If what you stated occurs it should be considered a bug.  This is akin to 2 processes trying to acquire a mutex or semaphore and both failing when nothing is currently holding the lock.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: On which file system do you observer this?

Comment: @alk I am not observing this. I am merely trying to access the correctness of the assumption that `flock(fd, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)` never fails spuriously. Do you know whether the flock() implementation depends on the file system?

Comment: `flock` doesn't work on some NFS file systems.  It depends on the implementation.

Comment: @Duck But does EXT4 and BTRFS have different `flock()` implementation, for example?

Comment: @Kristian Spangsege, I don't know but I imagine you have already googled it.  If there were problems I would guess it would have been widely reported.

Comment: @Duck These problems, even if they happen, are very rare. Locking typically takes less than 1/10 of a millisecond, and both processes need to call `flock` at the same time. It probably won't be so widely reported even if it is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [man flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html):

> EWOULDBLOCK
>       The file **is locked** and the LOCK_NB flag was selected.

So getting EWOULDBLOCK means the file is already locked. If it is guaranteed that your two processes are the only ones involved, they will never get EWOULDBLOCK on the same file at the same time.

Please note that threads is a different story. Threads normally share file descriptors, so several threads within the same process can call flock() successfully on the same file.